# What is the use of Core Data and why we need it in iPhone development?

Tags: iphone, core-data

What is meant by Core Data in iPhone? Why we need it? What is the basic methods in it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should go back to your previously asked questions and mark them as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is essentially an ORM for the iPhone SDK, allowing you to define objects that act as a model which can be created, updated, and deleted through the use of OO and without writing SQL.

If you want more detail I would suggest accepting answers on your other posts like others have already suggested.